# Problems with inheriting generics from Java

Tags: java, generics

An error was reported when the find method was called.

```
interface Node<N extends Node<N>> {
    void setNext(N next);
    N getNext();
}

interface Entry<K, V> extends Node<Entry<K, V>> {
    K getKey();
    void setValue(V value);
    V getValue();
}

class Test {
    public static <N extends Node<N>> N find(N base, Object obj) {
        for (N node = base; node != null; node = node.getNext())
            if (node.equals(obj))
                return node;
        return null;
    }

    public static <K, V, E extends Entry<K, V>> E getEntry(E[] table, K key) {
        return find(table[0], key);
    }
}
```

Bound mismatch: The generic method find(N, Object) of type Test is not applicable for the arguments (E, K). The inferred type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >

I do not know why this is so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
interface Node<N extends Node<N>> {
    void setNext(N next);
    N getNext();
}
interface Entry<K, V> extends Node<Entry<K, V>> {
    K getKey();
    void setValue(V value);
    V getValue();
}
```

You have `E extends Entry<E, V>`. What does `E.getNext()` return? Since `Entry<K, V> extends Node<Entry<K, V>>`, `E.getNext()` would *at least* return `Entry<K, V>`, that's for sure.

But will it be `E`? `Entry<K, V>.getNext()` is only guaranteed to return some instance of `Entry<K, V>`. But it is not guaranteed to return exactly the same type that `Entry<K, V>` actually is. There's nothing in the code forcing `E.getNext()` to return `E`, only *some* instance assignment-compatible to `Entry<K, V>`.

Therefore the best what can be inferred for your `find` method is `Entry<K, V>` which is not necessarily compatible to `E`.

Answer (score 2):

We know

```
E extends Entry<K, V>
```

and

```
Entry<K, V> extends Node<Entry<K, V>>
```

These two things together mean that

```
E extends Node<Entry<K, V>>
```

However in order for the  `find` method to be applicable we need

```
E extends Node<E>
```

but this does not follow, because `E` is only a subtype of `Entry<K, V>`, not equal to it.

The problem is that while `Node` has a type parameter representing its own concrete implementing type (`N`), `Entry` does not. You can fix it by adding a third type parameter for this purpose.

```
interface Entry<K, V, E extends Entry<K, V, E>> extends Node<E> {
    K getKey();
    void setValue(V value);
    V getValue();
}

public static <K, V, E extends Entry<K, V, E>> E getEntry(E[] table, K key) {
    return find(table[0], key);
}
```